# How to filter a table of data for matching values in a particular column

Tags: python, dataset, filtering

I have some very large tables I am trying to filter for multiple specific values.  For the sake of simplicity, let's say a table resembles the following:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 7 |
| 2 | 5 | 8 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 |

I would want to create a new table which only includes the rows where Column2 equals either 5 or 6.  So the new table would look like this:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | 8 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 |

My current code looks like this:
`new_table=table[('Column2')==(5 and 6)]`

I have also tried the "or" operator and a comma between 5 and 6.

Each of these options only gives me one row of output (the row with 6 in the middle column) when I should be getting two rows of output.  What should I be doing instead?

Comment: Are you using pandas or pure Python? pandas is the tool of choice for problems like this.

Comment: I'm using pure Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df={'a':[1,2,3],"b":[5,6,7],"c":[9,8,0]}

aa=[df["b"].index(x) for x in df["b"] if x==5 or x==6]

for x in df:
    for c in df[x]:
        b=df[x].index(c)
        if b not in aa:
            df[x].pop(b)
print(df)
```

I haven't checked speed for large data but this can solve your problem! If you have very large data then using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org) could be easy solution, because for these type of filtering there is very easy tools.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer, but unfortunately this did not work for me.  I will look into using pandas.

Comment: @codinggirl17 my bad there I wrote wrong! I had edited the answer. Please check. I am supposed to write `if b not in aa:` but my bad I wrote `if b in aa:`